# Intermarriage - contradiction in punishment according to Rambam?

Tags: halacha, rambam, intermarriage

In Sefer Hamitzvos, [negative commandment 52](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/961703/jewish/Negative-Commandment-52.htm) about marrying non-Jews, the Rambam says

> There are variations regarding the punishment for one who transgresses this prohibition. If he has relations with her in public, the punishment is carried out by one who kills him while he is in the act — as Pinchas did to Zimri.
>
> [...]
>
> **If, however, nobody knows of the act, or he separated from her before the zealous could kill him, his punishment is kares.**

From here it seems the Rambam holds that marrying a non-Jew punishable by kares. But in the Mishneh Torah, [Issurei Biah 12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960660/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Twelve.htm) he says

> When a Jew engages in relations with a woman from other nations, [taking her] as his wife or a Jewess engages in relations with a non-Jew as his wife, they are punished by lashes, according to Scriptural Law.

This seems to clearly say it's punishable by lashes.

How can these two statements be reconciled?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the sentence that you have bolded

> **If, however, nobody knows of the act, or he separated from her before the zealous
>   could kill him, his punishment is kares.**

speaks of a situation in which there are no witnesses that can convict him. The halacha requires that he have been warned by witnesses who can testify in bais din so that he can be convicted.

[Rambam Issurei Biah - Chapter Twelve Halacha 6](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960660/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Twelve.htm) explicitly says

> 6 If the zealous did not strike him, nor did he receive stripes from the
>   court,<sup>18</sup> his punishment is explicitly stated in the words
>   of the prophetic tradition. He is liable for karet,<sup>19</sup> as
>   [Malachi 2:11-12] states: "Judah desecrated that which is sacred to
>   God, [by] loving and engaging in relations with the daughter of a
>   foreign god. May God cut off from a man who does this any progeny and
>   descendant." [Implied is]<sup>20</sup> that if he is an Israelite, he
>   will not have progeny among the wise who will raise issues, nor a
>   descendant among the scholars who will respond. If he is a priest, he
>   will not have [a descendant] who "presents an offering to the Lord of
>   Hosts." Thus you have learned that a person who shares intimacy with a
>   gentile woman is considered as if he married a false deity, as the
>   verse states: "engaging in relations with the daughter of a foreign
>   god." And he is called one who "desecrated that which is sacred to
>   God."
>
> <sup>18.</sup> The Maggid Mishneh writes that if he was given "stripes
>   for rebellious conduct" by the court, he is no longer liable for
>   kereit. Our Sages (Makkot 23b) state a similar concept with regard to
>   a person who receives lashes for the violation of a Scriptural
>   prohibition. The Rambam extends the idea to include a person who is
>   punished on the basis of Rabbinic decree.
>
> <sup>19.</sup> This applies even if relations are conducted in
>   private.
>
> <sup>20.</sup> As interpreted by Yevamot 22b, 23a.

As pointed out in the [BACKGROUND TO THE DAILY DAF Yevamos 49](https://mail.dafyomi.co.il/yevamos/backgrnd/ye-in-049.htm)

> [line 3]כרתKARES (KARES AND MISAH B'YEDEI SHAMAYIM: Heavenly
>   Punishment of Untimely Death)
>
> (a)Some sins are so severe that they are punished with untimely death.
>   There are two types of untimely death that are used as heavenly
>   punishments: Kares, and Misah b'Yedei Shamayim. Kares means "being
>   severed" from the world and dying before one's time. Misah b'Yedei
>   Shamayim means "death at the hands of heaven." These punishments are
>   not administered by the courts, but through divinely administered
>   justice.
>
> (b)One who deliberately transgresses a commandment that is punishable
>   with either Kares or Misah b'Yedei Shamayim is punished even if there
>   are no witnesses to his act, and even if he was not warned at that
>   time of his transgression that his violation will result in his
>   untimely death.

Comment: In court it gets lashed but without court is gets Karet? Is there any other example of that phenomenon?

Comment: Yes I picked up references to other punishments including misa when I googled *"bais din punishments kares lashes"* however that would have made the posting to long to be easily readable. I also remember it from the daf yomi earlier. @DoubleAA

Comment: Ok, but usually the presence of witnesses produces a more severe punishment (eg execution by court for which teshuvah doesn’t help vs kares for which it does, etc). Yet here you’re saying it’s inverted and the presence of witnesses makes the punishment less severe - which seems strange. It is almost to the benefit of the perpetrator to make sure witnesses are watching, so he will only be lashed instead of dying. Something just doesn’t sound right about that.

Comment: @user9806 No it is not a matter of severity, but a matter of whether the jurisdiction is in bais din shel ma'aleh (heavenly court) or bais din shel matah (earthly court). In any case kares occurs only when the heavenly court is the one that decrees the sentence.

Comment: But it is about severity, as I’ve explained. The presence/absence of witnesses might dictate which jurisdiction is involved (earth court or heavenly) but the punishment should be equivalent. Getting lashed certainly seems (and is portrayed throughout halacha) as being a lesser punishment than dying (kares).

Comment: @user9806 You do not mention severity in the question and as I point out in the answer, it is strictly a matter of jurisdiction. No punishment can be used by the earthly court without witnesses and an appropriate trial. Only if the earthly court cannot convict and punish (in any way), will the heavenly court take jurisdiction. Thus, it does not matter if the punishment is lashes or one of the four types of death penalty. Notice the first words of the Rambam which equates the death by the zealous (like Zimri at the hands of Pinchas) and lashes. Your question about severity would apply there.

Comment: @user9806 he only gets lashes if the witnesses watching him don’t kill him. I really don’t think it’s in his best interests to “maybe die maybe get lashes” vs “get kares”.

Comment: @Loani Is it considered "in public", just because two witnesses are there? And even if it is, he can just get restrain the witnesses from hurting him, or get weak or young or feeble witnesses, etc., so there's no chance of them killing him.

Comment: @sabbahillel You're right that severity is not in my original question, and your answer does resolve the question itself (namely, the contradiction). But still, the resolution raises this question of severity inversion. Maybe it can be asked separately...(i.e. Why should the same sin be punished much less severely just because there _were_ witnesses. That goes against the general paradigm of witnesses implying a greater or equal punishment than without witnesses)

Comment: @doubleaa https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Makkot.3.15?lang=he

Comment: @joelk ya but that's bedieved

Comment: @doubleaa Bediavad that the witnesses should not have warned him for malkot, or, having done so, that the court should not have carried out the punishment?

Comment: @joelk the witnesses should warn correctly. If they didn't we still mete out the lower punishment

Comment: @DoubleAA Do you have a source for this? Looking through Rambam all I see is that *chayvei keritut* receive lashes if there are witnesses and a warning. Does he say anywhere that the witnesses shouldn't be warning him for lashes?

Comment: @joshk I don't have a source offhand, but how could it be that the witnesses wouldn't have to warn him accurately that he'd get Karet?

Comment: @DoubleAA If there are witnesses then they should warn what basis din will do not what shamaim will do. This they should warn about malkos. As said before kareis does not require warning

Comment: @sabba I didn't say kares requires warning. Beis Din will do nothing because the stated punishment, Karet, is not theirs to mete. That's what the witnesses should say. It's a true and accurate and realistic warning. Warning means to actually warn them of the consequences.

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought that hadra'ah only means what basis din would decree.

Comment: @sabba what beis din would decree is to do nothing since the punishment is Karet.